# ng-disabled not working on directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a directive of a button, with the ng-disabled attribute
I am trying to bind the ng-disabled status to a variable on my scope.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <btn dis="disableBtn"></btn>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .directive('btn', function() {
      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         scope: {
            dis: "@"
         },
         template: '<button ng-disabled="dis">click</button>',
         link: function($scope) {
            setInterval(function() {
                console.warn($scope.disableBtn);
                $scope.disableBtn = !$scope.disableBtn;
            }, 100);
      }
   };
});
```

The odd thing is - I see in the console that the value of `$scope.disableBtn` **does** change, yet the button disabled status does not.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not get why are you trying to create a new directive? Why dont you use the ng-disable from angular?

Comment: check your capitalization.  Angular changes `camelCase` to hyphenated like this: `camel-case`

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled expects an expression, but because you bind "dis" as a literal value (using '@') it will not evaluate correctly. You should use

```
scope: {
  dis: "="
},
```

to properly bind the boolean value.